# how to set tcp options (MSS value) in Net::RawIP

Tags: perl, sockets, tcp

Can i set Maximum segment size to some value when using Net::RawIP?

I am trying the below code but don't know how can i set MSS value in TCP options to custom value.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Net::RawIP;

$packet = new Net::RawIP;

$packet->set({
    ip  => {
        saddr => '192.168.122.128',
        daddr => '192.168.122.1'
    },
    tcp => { source => 2323,
        dest    => 8080,
        syn     => 1,
        seq     => 100,
        ack_seq => 0,
        data    => 'hello world'
    }
});

$packet->optset(tcp => { type => [ (2) ], data => [ (10) ] });

$packet->send(0, 1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::RawIP#optset-OPTPROTO-type-...-data):

> **optset(OPTPROTO => { type => [...],data => [...] },...)**
>
> [...] The value of the data also is an array reference. This array must be filled with *strings* which must contain all bytes from a option except bytes with type and length of an option.

(emphasis added)

You're passing a reference to an array of integers; you need to pass a reference to an array of strings. Try something like this:

```
$packet->optset( tcp => { type => [ 2 ], data => [ "\x00\x0A" ] } );
```

[The length of the maximum segment size field is 4](http://www.iana.org/assignments/tcp-parameters/tcp-parameters.xhtml), which includes one byte for the kind field, one byte for the length field, and two bytes for the data itself, so you need to pass a two-byte string as above.

Comment: thanks... it seems that data has to be passed as ASCII to set MSS value otherwise it will exceed the max bytes. Is there a way i can use decimal or hex?

Comment: @user2896215 `0x000A` *is* hex. What is the exact issue you're having?

Comment: @user2896215 Ah, looking at the source I think I see what you're talking about (I don't have a machine I can test on right now): try `data => [ "\x00\x0A" ]` instead. I didn't understand that `optset` wants binary strings (byte strings).